# a general relation having maximal element for any subset

Tags: terminology, relations

I am dealing with not necessarily transitive relations satisfying, however, a well-ordering-like property. i.e., for any subset there exist a maximum element.

In mathematical terms, say $R \subset X \times X$ is my relation, and for any  $Y \subset X$ the set of maximal elements $max_R(Y) \equiv  \{ y \in Y | y R z,  \forall z \in Y  \} $ is non-empty.

Is there any name of this property of relation R? It seems to be strange to call it well-ordering property, when the relation itself is not ordering (terminology for ordering or lattices is useless since no transitivity is assumed).

Thank you.

Comment: I wouldn't say this is the basic property of orderings. That really confuses things. If you have the property of having a max element for every finite set and yet don't have transitivity it's very far from being an ordering since you get pretty much something where you must get $yRx$ and $xRy$ for $x\neq y$. Yet for posets that's exactly what you don't want so this is IMO far from an ordering. Also calling this maximality seems strange. It seems closer to some graph theoretic stuff like being a sink or something.

Comment: Hello and thanks, based on your comment, I rephrased the question using the notion of well-ordering. You are right, I totally agree with "it's very far from being an ordering".. , I removed the confusing part of my question. However, I don't follow your next statement saying "you get pretty much something where you must get yRx and xRy for x≠y", why?

Comment: Well suppose that doesn't happen, that is $\forall x,y\; (yRx\wedge xRy)\implies x=y$. Now if transitivity doesn't hold there exist $x,y,z$ such that $x R y$ and $y R z$ but not $x R z$. But by your principle you have a maximal element for $\{x,z\}$ thus you get $z R x$. Now look at $\{x,y,z\}$ this must have a maximal element. It can't be $x$ since $x R z$ doesn't hold. It can't be $y$ by assumption since then $x R y$ and $y R x$ and it can't be $z$ by assumption because then $y R z$ and $z R y$. So we conclude if $\forall x,y\; (yRx\wedge xRy)\implies x=y$ then $R$ is transitive.

Comment: A comment is a bit short for a proof so I will point out a couple things I use without stating above. Having the maximality property you state means any two elements are comparable since $\{x,y\}$ has a maximal element for all $x,y$. It also implies that $R$ is symmetric i.e. $x R x$ since $\{x\}$ has a maximal element. I use the first to conclude that if we don't have $x R z$ we must have $z R x$ and I use the second to ignore situations where $x,y,z$ are not distinct which are the two other ways of breaking transitivity.

Comment: It might be worthwhile to check what happens when you mod out by these kinds of classes but I'm guessing you will collapse the relation heavily. This is the type of problem that really benefits from being able to draw though.

Comment: I see, thanks. Originally I just thought that you meant **yRx** and **xRy** for **ALL** **x≠y**, then it would be truly useless definition .-)

Comment: it might be interesting to know what the motivation is, but I would certainly add graph-theory to the tags since this does seem close. The maximality property you have is very powerful as you can see since it makes transitivity fail in a very special way and it forces $R$ to be reflexive and total.

Comment: I try to formalise some alternative theory of preferences. In such a context it seems to be natural that R is both reflexive and total. However, your remarks well illustrated why there is no definition of 'maximality property', the proposed one is just too strong to be useful. This is already interesting observation on its own.